# Magento 2: Add CSS class to ui_component listing table

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to add a custom CSS class to the ui_component listing table. The listing table is created as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">aw_helpdesk2_ticket_frontend_listing.aw_helpdesk2_ticket_frontend_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <spinner>aw_helpdesk2_ticket_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>aw_helpdesk2_ticket_frontend_listing.aw_helpdesk2_ticket_frontend_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
```

I tried adding

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">custom-class</item>
</item>
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="custom_class" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

Column field

```
<field name="home_preference_sequence">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">337</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Home Preference Sequence</item>
                    **<item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="admin__field_home_preference_sequence" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>**
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Comment: I added this inside <argument> and ran commands but not working

Comment: Magento allows to add of CSS for column or field